# Unable to request cluster with one GPU on GKE

Tags: gpu, google-kubernetes-engine, quota

I'm trying to create a minimal cluster with 1 node and 1 GPU/node. My command:

```
gcloud container clusters create cluster-gpu     --num-nodes=1     --zone=us-central1-a      --machine-type="n1-highmem-2"  --accelerator="type=nvidia-tesla-k80,count=1"     --scopes="gke-default,storage-rw"
```

creates the cluster. Now when the following pod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gke-training-pod-gpu
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-custom-container
    image: gcr.io/.../object-classification:gpu
    resources:
      limits:
        nvidia.com/gpu: 1
```

is applied to my cluster, I can see in the GKE dashboard that the `gke-training-pod-gpu` pod is never created. When I do the same as above, only replacing `num-nodes=1` by `num-nodes=2`, this time I get the following error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "NVIDIA_K80_GPUS": request requires '2.0' and is short '1.0'. project has a quota of '1.0' with '1.0' available. View and manage quotas at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?usage=USED&project=...`

Is there any way to use a GPU when the quota is 1?

EDIT:

when pod has been created with `kubectl apply` command, a `kubectl describe pod gke-training-pod-gpu` command shows following event:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  48s (x2 over 48s)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient nvidia.com/gpu.
```

Comment: Do you want to troubleshoot why the pod is not being created with only one node or want to increase the quota?

Comment: I want to troubleshoot why the pod is not created with only one node

Comment: Can you first run 'kubectl describe pod gke-training-pod-gpu' and add the events output to your original post? Or, if the pod does not even have a status, what is the error message when you attempt to create the pod?

Comment: Original post edited

Comment: Did you install the NVIDIA GPU device drivers on your worker node?
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#installing_drivers

Comment: @GariSingh you should add your comment as an answer so I can accept it: I installed the device drivers and it worked (I thought at the beginning that I have to do it *after* the pod creation). Thanks!

Comment: @Patrick added below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to [install the NVIDIA CPU device driver](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#installing_drivers) on your worker node(s).

Running

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-accelerators/master/nvidia-driver-installer/cos/daemonset-preloaded.yaml
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution as I see it is to request a quota increase in the [IAM & Admin Quotas page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas).

As for the reason this is happening, I can only imagine that both the node and the pod are requesting GPUs, but only the node is getting it because of the capped quota.

Comment: Agreed with this answer. You can also describe the node and see the GPU resources taken just to validate it.

Comment: You're probably right. Can you explain why on the quota page (filtered for NVIDIA_K80_GPUS) I can see a limit of 1 for Location us-central1 and Unlimited for Location us-central1-a ?

Comment: No idea. Perhaps changing region might allow you to run more than one GPU.

Comment: @patrick, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65725504/adding-gke-node-pool-with-gpu-using-terraform) should answer your question about unlimited, zone and regional.